# Pass current user filter to ssrs hidden parameter

Tags: web-part, reporting-services, hidden, report-viewer

I have a SSRS report hosted in sharepoint (in Report Viwer Webpart).That report has a hidden parameter "username". I want to pass current user to that ssrs report. But when I tried to connect to Current User Filter web part to Report Viewer Webpart, "username" hidden parameter is not at all displaying.

Is there any settings need to be done, to connect filter web parts to the hidden parameter?

I know we can **pass value to hidden parameter through URL**, but for some reasons we dont want to expose user name in URL.

Please suggest your ideas. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting the default value for the user parameter in SSRS to User!UserID . That's what that property is for. Then you are not passing the username as a string in the URL.

Comment: Got it :) Thank you so much. I have updated my SSRS to have that. But want to learn, can't we connect ssrs hidden parameter and URL filter webpart?

Comment: As far as I know, the web part connection is only possible with the parameter set to Visible. Once it's set to visible, then it's available from the Web Part connection menu. If there parameter is hidden, it's not shown in the Send To options on the Web Part.